# Не могу разобраться с логикой задания

Tags: c++

На учёбе выдали вот такое задание:

> Разработать программу, для обработки информации о
>   строительных материалах: поступление, учет и отгрузка. Для этого
>   требуется разработать классы. Базовый класс должен быть абстрактным.
>   Первый производный класс определяет количество стройматериалов каждого
>   типа, например 50 перекрытий. Другой класс хранит данные о каждом виде
>   стройматериалов, например площадь и стоимость за квадратный метр.
>   Далее следует класс, хранящий описание каждого вида стройматериалов,
>   которое включает название и сорт материала.

Помогите разобраться, как эта иерархия вообще должна выглядеть?

• Почему один класс хранит информацию обо всех видах стройматериалов?

• Базовый класс должен быть абстракцией чего?

• Да вообще куча вопросов, не понимаю само задание.

Буду рад любой помощи: перефразируйте, сделайте рисунок, ну или что-то подобное.

Comment: В данном случае абстрактный класс "Стройматериалы" является обобщением (абстракцией) всех видов стройматериалов, поступающих на склад и требующих размещения, учёта и отгрузки. В зависимости от степени детализации, могут потребоваться и другие абстрактные классы, например, по конкретному виду стройматериалов: пиломатериалы, металлопрокат, покрытия, смеси и т.д. Чтение учебника по ООП поможет разобраться в задании. Но пересказать его содержание здесь не представляется возможным.

Comment: Тут имеется в виду, что следующий это не обязательно один. На верху абстрактный, а на следующем уровне три потомка и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждая задача имеет многие способы решения. Перед вами стоит задача и конкретный способ решения.

> Почему один класс хранит информацию обо всех видах стройматериалов?

ответ на подобные вопросы однозначен: **Потому что предлагается именно такой способ решения**.

Для этого нужно просто взять ручку с бумагой и записывать точно так же, как требуется(если опыта не хватает для решения сходу): 
 Нужно обработать информации о строительных материалах:

- поступление,
- учет,
- отгрузка.

Как обработать,  вы пока не решили(не знаете), но вы точно знаете, что для каждого из этих пунктов вы должны выполнять какие_то действия, а значит их можно написать в виде функций, которые и станут методами абстрактного класса  `Складское_помещение`,  или, вернее, `информация о поступлении строительных материалов`, поскольку вы еще не знаете что и как должно выполниться.  Записывая, таким образом, информацию о том, что нужно делать, мы можем написать  **первоначальный** вид наших классов. Например так:

```
class Info {
protected:  
    using Record = std::map<std::string, size_t>;
    Record map; //записывается название и количество
public:
    //поступление материалов
    virtual  size_t contains(const size_t);
    //учет материалов
    virtual Record& registration() = 0;
    //отправка
    virtual void dispatch() = 0;
};
//класс, определяющий  количество материалов каждого типа
class Identify : public Info {  
public:     
    Record& registration() final {/*...*/ }
    void dispatch() final {/*...*/ }
};
//описание
class Dep : public Info {
    //информацию получать из map
    enum Kind { I, II, III }; // какого сорта
public:     
    Record& registration() final;
    void dispatch() final;
    //количество поступившего материал
    size_t contains(const size_t) final;        
    //тут функция, для выдачи(вывода) названия и сорта
    //каким то образом(способ выбирайте сами)
};
```

Следующим делом является обнаружение недостатков, написанного. Лично я, пока не стал разбираться в каком классе какие методы стоит определять, и, следовательно, какие методы (не) нужно представлять как чисто виртуальными...

Comment: @Maxgmer, Не замечая Ваши грамматические поправки, я начал править код и автоматически откланил ваши поправки. Спасибо, вы все правильно заметили